# how to link python pandas dataframe to mysqlconnector '%s' value

Tags: mysql-connector

I am trying to pipe a webscraped pandas dataframe into a MySql table with mysql.connector but I can't seem to link df values to the %s variable. The connection is good (I can add individual rows) but it just returns errors when I replace the value witht he %s.

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host = 'ip', user = 'user', passwd = 'pass', database = 'db')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
insert_df = ("""INSERT INTO table"
                 "(page_1, date_1, record_1, task_1)" 
                 "VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s')""")
cursor.executemany(insert_df, df)
cnx.commit()
cnx.close()
```

This returns "ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

If I add any additional oiperations it returns "ProgrammingError: Parameters for query must be an Iterable."

I am very new to this so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work around for me was to redo my whole process. I ran sqlalchemy, all the documentation makes this very easy. message if you want the code I used.